# NA values do not appear when importing from excel

Tags: r, na

I have an excel table with some empty cells. Specifically, I have 2 columns: column 1 has some empty cells, column 2 has all empty cells.

The problem is that when I import the table into R the empty cells in column 1 are empty, while in column 2 there is NA. I need NA to appear in all of them.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or at least some way to fix it.

I import this table into R using `read.csv` or `read.csv2` or `data.table::fread`, but it's the same with both.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Save the excel file in .csv format. It gives accurate result (NA in empty values of both column).           df <- read.csv("file.csv").

Answer (score 0):

First, you can save the excel file as .csv file containing the NA values. Then you can simply use `read.csv("data.csv")`. All the empty cells will be represented by NA only.

Answer (score 0):

For `read.csv2()` try adding the argument `na.strings =` and specify all the strings you want to be interpreted as NA, eg. `c("NA", "N/A", "na", " ")` etc...

Make sure in the excel spreadsheet that the 'empty' cells don't contain spaces and other characters that would appear to be empty space.